# How can I automatically refactor my classes to use the default namespace for the folder they're in?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, refactoring, namespaces

I've been playing around with the structure of my project, and I'd like to reset the namespaces of my classes to what the default would be. That is, the default namespace for the project, plus each of the folders in the hierarchy.

It's not as simple as just find + replace, since I've both added and renamed some folders, and files from some namespaces were split into multiple other namespaces. I'm using VS 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think this is not something you can do natively with Visual Studio.

Resharper, however, appears to have exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Adjust_Namespaces

Comment: I had a hunch this was the case... looks like it might be time to invest in a resharper license.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm in the same boat.